# Groovy task in ant file without explicit taskdef?

Tags: groovy, ant

Disclaimer: Ant Noob!

I'm trying to get the groovy task running in ant. Works so far:

```
<project>
  <taskdef name="groovy"
         classname="org.codehaus.groovy.ant.Groovy"
         classpath="C:/Local/groovy-2.4.5/lib/groovy-ant-2.4.5.jar;C:/Local/groovy-2.4.5/lib/groovy-2.4.5.jar"/>

  <echo message="Hello!"/>
  <groovy>
    println "Hello from Groovy!"
  </groovy>
</project>
```

What I can't get behind (even reading [this](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/antlib.html) and related entries) is what I need to do to my Ant installation (Windows) to make the script run like so, without the `taskdef` or any other reference in my project specific build file:

```
<project>
  <echo message="Hello!"/>
  <groovy> <!-- Would be nice if I could treat this like a built-in -->
    println "Hello from Groovy!"
  </groovy>
</project>
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to put all Groovy dependencies (`groovy-ant.jar`, `groovy.jar`, etc) on the classpath that is read by Ant. The easiest way is to store them under *ANT_HOME*/lib. Or you can pass them using the `-lib` option on the command line.

Then you would still have to tell Ant about the path of the antlib. You can use the antlib namespace mechanism described in the [documentation page](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/antlib.html). You specify the package that contains the `antlib.xml` in the namespace URI, in this case `org.codehaus.groovy`:

```
<project xmlns:groovy="antlib:org.codehaus.groovy">
   <echo message="Hello!"/>
   <groovy:groovy>
      println "Hello from Groovy!"
   </groovy:groovy>
</project>
```

Note that you can still use `taskdef` *without* referencing the Jar file if it is placed (with its dependencies) in *ANT_HOME*/lib. You just reference the path of the antlib resource in the Jar. In this case you can do without the namespace URI:

```
<project>
    <taskdef resource="org/codehaus/groovy/antlib.xml"/>
    <echo message="Hello!"/>
    <groovy>
        println "Hello from Groovy!"
    </groovy>
</project>
```

Comment: Ok. That is already pretty helpful when I don't have to manage any explicit reference to the jars. But is there really no way around the boilerplate? Isn't there some default properties file in the ant installation where one could record this?

Comment: @MartinBa To my knowledge there is no place for default definitions -- Ant loads the predefined tasks in its Java initialization code. Note that you can use `taskdef` _without_ referencing the Jar if they are in `ANT_HOME/lib`. You just reference the path of the antlib resource: `<taskdef resource="org/codehaus/groovy/antlib.xml"/>`.